# Como fazer um CRUD via REST

Tags: delphi, web-service, mobile, rest, lado-do-cliente

### Introdução

Eu preciso acessar um web service em PHP via aplicação mobile.

Já vi vários vídeos e li muitos tutoriais a respeito do REST Client do Delphi.

Consegui inclusive desenvolver um protótipo da minha aplicação.

---

### Problema

Porém o problema é que em todos os materiais que eu vi, mostram exemplos com uma única funcionalidade. Todas as aplicações de exemplo realizam uma listagem ou uma busca de um web service, nunca fazem algo como "Criar um registro e depois listar" ou "Buscar um registro e atualizar ele".

---

### Dúvida

**Gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor prática para realizar um "CRUD" por exemplo...**

Eu iria utilizar apenas um RESTClient/RESTRequest/RESTResponse/ETC.
E a partir disso, realizar as operações pelo código, alterando as propriedades do RESTRequest/ETC de acordo com a necessidade/tela, e fazer todos os tratamentos na mão.

**OU**

Eu iria ter vários RESTRequests/ETC, para cada operação que eu possa precisar (E quem sabe colocar eles dentro de um DM).

Pois com isto, eu iria conseguir fazer os LiveBindings e fazer os tratamentos dos dados sem muito sofrimento.

**OU**

Tanto faz o modo como é feito, ambas as formas estariam corretas e poderiam ser mescladas.

Ex: Criar um TRESTRequest para listar "produtos", outro para listar "clientes" e outro para realizar operações de Create/Update/Delete

Comment: Daniel, aqui não usamos "resolvido" no título. O correto é marcar sua resposta como "correta".

Comment: Está certo, obrigado pela correção. Amanhã eu irei marcar a resposta como "correta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, eu acabei encontrando a resposta.

O correto seria criar diversos RESTRequest/ETC dependendo da sua necessidade.

Se o componente que você está mexendo está utilizando LiveBindings, crie um RESTRequest/ETC em específico para ele, por que depois fica muito mais fácil para recarregar uma lista por exemplo.

E para operações como "Adicionar/Deletar/ETC" que não necessitam utilizar alguma coisa em específico nas telas, utilizem um RESTRequest/ETC em comum para estas operações, e modifique no código a url e parâmetros específicos para as operações.

---

**EX:**

```
procedure TForm1.savebtnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    LJson: TJSONObject;
begin
    RESTResponse2.RootElement := 'object';

    RESTRequest2.Resource := 'v1/groupProductService';

    RESTRequest2.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    RESTRequest2.Params.AddItem('nome_grupo', nome_grupoEdit.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

    RESTRequest2.Execute;

    LJson := RESTRequest2.Response.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Text := LJson.ToString;
end;
```

Neste caso, estou criando um registro no banco de dados na minha tabela de grupos (O único parâmetro é o nome do grupo).

Notem que este é o meu segundo RESTRequest, o primeiro ele faz LiveBinding com uma listView que carrega todos os grupos registrados.

Então eu crio um evento no clique do botão salvar.

Defino o RootElement do meu JSON.

Seto a URL do meu webservice.

Defino qual tipo de request ele irá executar (POST/PUT/ETC).

Adiciono os parâmetros que serão enviados.

Executo a request (é aqui que o registro é adicionado)

Então eu exibo o retorno em um Memo.

Neste caso, só faltaria eu executar novamente o RESTRequest1 para recarregar a lista de grupos (que isto eu ainda não fiz).

---

Espero que isto possa ajudar alguém, e caso alguma coisa que eu tenha dito esteja errado, por favor me corrija.

Obrigado.